# NAudio Mp3Frame is null while streaming mp3

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, naudio

I am trying to make an mp3 player by streaming. The mp3 file which is on the internet source can be played in real-time in this project. Also I want to make it supports Pause, Stop, Forward, Backward. To get these features, I need to write a flexible player.

**So I wrote this code:**

```
    WaveOut outer;
    AcmMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor;
    BufferedWaveProvider provider;
    public void Play()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Mp3Frame frame;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[30000];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ReadFullyStream fully = new ReadFullyStream(ms);

            do
            {
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(fully);
                if (decompressor == null)
                {
                    decompressor = CreateFrameDecompressor(frame) as AcmMp3FrameDecompressor;
                    provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
                    provider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
                    outer = new WaveOut();
                    outer.Init(provider);
                    outer.Play();
                }
                int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
                provider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
            }
            while (bytesRead > 0);
        });

    }
```

In the code above it throws an exception because of the frame is null. It means `LoadMp3FromStream` doesn't work for `MemoryStream`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a null MP3 frame then this simply means it could not find an MP3 frame in the input data. So are you sure it's valid MP3 you are passing in.

Also you may want to check out my blog post about [playing streaming MP3](http://markheath.net/post/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using) and see if that code works for your file.

Comment: I implemented this code with changes from `Mp3StreamingDemo/MP3StreamingPanel.cs`. The problem in here is solved by removing ReadFullyStream and repositioning MemoryStream. I forgot the question to delete, sorry. Now I have a more important question related to memory using while streaming. I will be appreciated if you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544929/how-to-stream-an-mp3-file-from-a-url-without-using-much-ram. Thanks @Mark.