# How to stream an mp3 file from a URL without using much RAM?

Tags: c#, streaming, filestream, naudio, memorystream

I have a method to stream mp3 from url sources. In this method, the file begins downloading and at the same time the downloaded bytes are stored in a MemoryStream. But I realized that this method is not good. Because the RAM usage is approximately 50 mb when the mp3 file is being played.

So I want to make it without storing in MemoryStream. I tried storing the downloaded bytes in a temporary file, but it didn't worked. How to fix it to work with FileStream?

**It works good using MemoryStream:**

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
int bytesRead = 0;
long pos = 0;
int total = 0;

do
{
   bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, bigBuffer, total, bytesRead);
   total += bytesRead;
   pos = ms.Position;
   ms = new MemoryStream(bigBuffer);
   ms.Position = pos;
   frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(ms);

   //Other codes to play mp3...
}
while (bytesRead > 0 || waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing);
```

**This code throws exception on the LoadFromStream line with FileStream**

```
int bytesRead = 0;
long pos = 0;
int total = 0;
string path =Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"temp.mp3");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
do
{
   bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   total += bytesRead;
   pos = fs.Position;
   fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   fs.Position = pos;
   frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(fs);

   //Other codes to play mp3...
}
while (bytesRead > 0 || waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing);
```

Comment: 50Mb doesn't sound particularly excessive. If you understand how the .NET garbage collector works you will understand that sometimes memory isn't freed immediately even if it's not being used. Unless you are running out of RAM, or the usage continuously rises, I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mark. The main problem is here was to store the whole mp3 data in a byte array. I solved this issue using temporary file and reading the only necessary part of the stream. At that time I asked this question, I didn't know how to do it. After some challenging research, I did it. Now RAM usage is about 10 mb and steady. I answered my own question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556670/how-to-stream-an-mp3-file-using-a-temporary-file?noredirect=1#comment66424998_39556670