# How to stream an mp3 file using a temporary file?

Tags: c#, filestream, audio-streaming

I am working an Mp3 streamer. To stream mp3 file from url, I want to use a temporary file. But trying to read and write the same file throws `IOException` for `File.ReadAllBytes` because the file is in use. How can I get throught this problem?

```
long pos = 0;
string path = pathtothetempfile;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, 
                              FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

do
{
   bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

   fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   fs.Flush();

   byte[] tempBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

   pos = ms.Position;
   ms = new MemoryStream(tempBuffer);
   ms.Position = pos;

   frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(ms);

   //....codes....
}
while(bytesRead > 0)
```

Comment: Use the Explorer to test if it is possible to access the file while it is open: Try to copy the file somewhere. If this fails the program that has opened the file disallows shared access and you can't do anything in your program to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer by myself by searching so much. This answer contains NAudio to control the Mp3 and it is RAM friendly by reading stream partially. I am sharing it for other people who has the same problem.

```
    WaveOut waveOut;
    AcmMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor;
    BufferedWaveProvider provider;
    bool firstPlay = true;

    public void Play()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {

            #region WebRequest creator
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            if (avgbytes < 0)
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
                response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                contentLength = response.ContentLength;
            }
            else
                response = Helper.CreateAudioWebRequest(url, currentTime, avgbytes)
                                 .GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            #endregion

            #region Local Variables
            byte[] buffer = new byte[17 * 1024];
            byte[] bigBuffer = new byte[response.ContentLength];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            long pos = 0;
            long postotal = 0;
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".mp3";
            #endregion

            Mp3Frame frame;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,
                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            do
            {
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                fs.Flush();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ReadPartial(fs, postotal, 1024 * 10)))
                {
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(ms);
                    if (frame == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    pos = ms.Position;
                    postotal += pos;
                }


                #region First Play
                if (firstPlay)
                {
                    avgbytes = new Mp3WaveFormat(frame.SampleRate, frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2,
                frame.FrameLength, frame.BitRate).AverageBytesPerSecond;
                    duration = (int)(response.ContentLength * 1d / avgbytes);
                    firstPlay = false;
                }
                #endregion

                #region Decompress Frame
                if (decompressor == null)
                {
                    decompressor = CreateFrameDecompressor(frame) as AcmMp3FrameDecompressor;
                    provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
                    provider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
                }
                int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
                #endregion

                #region BufferedWaveProvider Area
                if (IsBufferNearlyFull(provider))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                provider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
                #endregion


                if (provider.BufferedDuration.TotalSeconds >= 2 && waveOut == null)
                {
                    waveOut = new WaveOut();
                    waveOut.Init(provider);
                    waveOut.Play();
                }
            }
            while (postotal != contentLength || bytesRead > 0 || waveOut==null || 
                        (waveOut != null && waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing));

        });
    }

    public static byte[] ReadStreamPartially(System.IO.Stream stream, long offset, long count)
    {
        long originalPosition = 0;

        if (stream.CanSeek)
        {
            originalPosition = stream.Position;
            stream.Position = offset;
        }

        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
            byte[] total = new byte[count];
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int byteRead;

            while ((byteRead = stream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                Buffer.SetByte(total, totalBytesRead, (byte)byteRead);
                totalBytesRead++;
                if (totalBytesRead == count)
                {
                    stream.Position = originalPosition;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (totalBytesRead < count)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[totalBytesRead];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(total, 0, temp, 0, totalBytesRead);
                stream.Position = originalPosition;
                return temp;
            }
            return total;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream.CanSeek)
            {
                stream.Position = originalPosition;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsBufferNearlyFull(BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider)
    {
        return bufferedWaveProvider != null &&
               bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes
               < bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 4;
    }
    private static IMp3FrameDecompressor CreateFrameDecompressor(Mp3Frame frame)
    {
        WaveFormat waveFormat = new Mp3WaveFormat(frame.SampleRate, frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2,
            frame.FrameLength, frame.BitRate);
        return new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(waveFormat);
    }
```